# SQL Substract min from max on a set of values where criteria is found in another table

Tags: sql, ms-access

[image: I have a table]

and I want for each unique CardID and for each Day individually to calculate MAX(Hour) - MIN(Hour) and sort them ascending by the values of Day column with a single entry of the CardID, number of hours worked and the day they registered the hours.

I am using Microsoft Access, so I need a query for that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add and the expected output based on your sample data. [Formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Comment: What is the criteria from other table?